# What is the first movie to repeat the same sequence multiple times with different camera angles?

Tags: first-appearance

What is the first movie to repeat the sequence with different camera angle?

For example, in *[Jackie Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Brown_(film))* (1997) there is a scene where Jackie went shopping, then again the same sequence is repeated with different camera angles with Louis Gara & Melanie Ralston secretly watching jackie's shopping.

Then, the sequence repeats again with Max Cherry watching both Louis Gara & Melanie Ralston *and* Jackie's shopping.

So, what is the first movie to repeat the same sequence multiple times with different camera angles?

Comment: Can't recall if [Rashomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon) does this, but I wouldn't be surprised if it does.

Comment: Rashomon does not, as each narrative is distinctly different in setup, dialog and resolution.  (Just rewatched last week).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THE LIFE OF AN AMERICAN FIREMAN (1903) does this, as we see a fireman perform a rescue from outside a house, and then again from inside the house. Director Edwin S. Porter was not trying to be clever. Modern- style editing had not really been invented yet.